# Force http in one url, wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

All my Wordpress site redirects to https by default, it is set in Plesk, what I need is that for a specific url goes to http: https://example.com/wp-content/campaign/listener.php needs redirection to http://example.com/wp-content/campaign/listener.php.

Https is set by default Plesk, I didn't change anything in .htaccess.

How can I get that redirection either from inserting some code in the PHP file or modifying .htaccess?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can’t do this at all, as long as you have a general redirection from HTTP to HTTPS configured on the Plesk level. Even if you did try to “revert” that by issuing a redirect to HTTP from within your WP system, that would in all likelihood only create an endless redirect loop then. You need to start by removing the redirect in Plesk altogether, and then handle the whole thing from within your WP system.

Comment: @misorude thank you for your reply

Comment: You can't redirect HTTPS to HTTP if it's defined by server. If you still apply rule then your site will be converted in infinite loop.